# VC++ environment

Tags: visual-c++, linker, libraries

I have been wracking my brains on openCV and openFrameworks for quite a while now. I have to configure my VC++2010 for this. I need information on how everything works. You know, how everything is interconnected.

Things I already know:
1. We include directories containing .h files so that we get the objects and function definitions

Except this, everything is very hazy.
A particular area is the libraries part! I have no clue about them.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning it can be very tricky to start new projects in openFrameworks.
The best way to start a project is to copy one of the existing examples and rename it.

If you like to include other addons you can check this little help page I made
http://www.lab101.be/playmore/of-addons-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, all compiler options, linker options, debugger settings, and custom build steps are exposed as properties.

You use a project’s property pages to view and modify its properties. You can apply project properties independently to any combination of build configuration (Debug or Release) and target platform (Win32, x64, or ARM). You can also set properties for individual files in a project.

Although you can set "global" properties on a per-user, per-computer basis, I no longer recommend it. Instead, I recommend that you use **Property Manager** to create a property sheet to store the settings for each kind of project that you want to be able to reuse or share with others.

To display **Property Manager**, on the menu bar, choose **View, Other Windows, Property Manager.**

The Visual C++ project system is based on **MSBuild**. Although you can edit the XML project files and property sheets directly on the command line, I recommend that you use the IDE.

A project file is an XML file that has the file name extension .**vcxproj**. All the properties that you set in the IDE are written to the project file directly or to property sheets that are imported at build time.

In general, here's how to set properties for a project:

**To set a property for a project**

1. On the menu bar, choose **Project, Properties**. Or in **Solution Explorer** or **Property Manager**, open the shortcut menu for the project and then choose **Properties**. The **Property Pages** dialog box opens.
2. In the boxes at the top of the dialog box, select the configurations and platforms that you want the setting to apply to.
   To create or modify the configurations that appear in the **Configuration** box, choose the **Configuration Manager** button.
3. Set the property value. When you choose the **OK** button, the new value is written to the project file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Include directories containing .h files so that we get the objects and function definitions.
2. Include directories containing .lib files so that you could link up your code with the already available library functions.
3. Include any of the dll which you might be using in your project.
4. Use Macro's (#include) wherever necessary.
5. If any library function is not getting linked properly, confirm in the registry editor if the dll is registered properly. If not try to register it manually.

I hope this information might help you out. :)